# How to parse newlines in XML Tags?

Tags: java, android, parsing, dom, xml-parsing

I am parsing a RSS feed, in that **`<description>`** tag contains some \n line characters like this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss version="2.0">
<item>
      <guid>http://www.horseandhound.co.uk/blogs/7619/314307.html</guid>
      <title>Chloe Chubb&#039;s s<title>Chloe Chubb&#039;s showing blog: Horse of the Year Show (HOYS) preparations</title>
      <description>So it is a week before HOYS and I have somehow managed to stay a bit oblivious to it all. It is only when I log onto Facebook and see the many, many statuses talking about it that I realise it’s only just around the corner! Then the butterflies begin.
&lt;br /&gt;
 /&gt;
My pre-HOYS diet was going well until last weekend when me and my best mates headed for a weekend away by the beach. Cue huge amounts of cheese, wine and cake and with the 5 pounds I’d lost, 2 went straight back on.&amp;#8230;</description>
      <url>http://www.horseandhound.co.uk/blogs/7619/314307.html</url>
</item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

Here I am able to parse the text up to first line "some text in line1.." but from the next line, the remaining text is not parsed. I am using Dom parser .Please suggest how to resolve this.

Comment: How are you *trying* to parse it? (Note that this is a text node, not the value of an attribute as per your title.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the entity `&#10;` to represent a newline in an XML attribute.
`&#13;` can be used to represent a carriage return.
A windows style CRLF could be represented as `&#13;&#10;`.

See [XML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#wf-Legalchar) for more details.

Comment: these are tutorials for parsing XML...[tutorial1](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-xml-parsing-tutorial/) & [tutorial2](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/).